# How to get result of a Word VBA function in c#?

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, office-interop

I need to open a Microsoft Office Word document and get the result of a function of a module in that document:

VBA module(*MainModule*):

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetResult() As String
    GetResult = "My Expected Result"
End Function
```

I tried some codes and latest is: <sup>[[Reference]](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306683)</sup>

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using MsWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

...

var wordApp = new MsWord.Application();
wordApp.DisplayAlerts = MsWord.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
wordApp.Visible = true;
wordApp.AutomationSecurity = MsoAutomationSecurity.msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;

MsWord._Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileNameObject,  ref falseValue, ref trueValue, ref falseValue,
    ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue,
    ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref falseValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue);    

object n;
n = wordApp.Run("GetResult");
// or
n = wordApp.Run("MainModule.GetResult");
// or 
n = RunMacro(wordApp, new Object[] {"MainModule.GetResult"});
// or
n = RunMacro(wordApp, new Object[] {"GetResult"});
// or
n = wordApp.Run("MainModule.GetResult", ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue, ref missingValue);

...

private static object RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
{
    return oApp.GetType()
        .InvokeMember("Run", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oApp, oRunArgs);
}
```

The error at `RunMacro` line is:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   [Inner-Exception]: Unable to run the specified macro

stack trace is:

> ```
> at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
> at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
> at System.Type.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args)
> at ConsoleApplicationTest.Program.RunMacro(Object oApp, Object[] oRunArgs) in c:\..\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplicationTest\ConsoleApplicationTest\Program.cs:line 57
> at ConsoleApplicationTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\..\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplicationTest\ConsoleApplicationTest\Program.cs:line 32
> ```

Note:
My Word document is saved as an Office 97-2003 document by Office 2013.
And *Macro Settings* is *Enable all macros*.
And *Trust access to the VBA project object model* is also checked.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, you can run a VBA macro with Application.Run ""macroName" (like you do) but it has to be a Sub with no return value. You need to find some workaround to get back a returned value.

Comment: @A.S.H thanks and it was my first try ;).

Comment: Doesn't `n = wordApp.Run("MainModule.GetResult");` work? Does the function take parameters?

Comment: @Mat'sMug it does. I mean the run method does have a return value. My first comment was wrong. I just had never used it that way, sorry (just tested it with excel, i guess it should be similar with word).

Comment: It is. But other Office apps have other specs for valid calls. Excel allows you to qualify the project name too, and Outlook just doesn't have a `Run` method to its `Application` class.

Comment: So just to clarify: Does `n = wordApp.Run("MainModule.GetResult");` work for you, while any call to `RunMacro` fails?

Comment: Yes fails - In my above code I wrote some `n = ...` codes those all of them faild.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked perfectly in vb.net. I am sure you can easily translate it to C#:

VB.Net:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        Dim wdApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
        Dim wdDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
        wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\SO\Abc.docm")
        Dim s As String = wdApp.Run("myFunc", "Hello World!")
        MsgBox(s)
        wdDoc.Close(False) : wdApp.Quit()
    End Sub
End Class
```

VBA Word:

```
Function myFunc(str As String) As String
    myFunc = str
End Function
```

p.s: VS2015, Word2007, Office12

EDIT
surprisingly, when i added to my code the security setting that you have added in yours, that is, `... = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`, I got a failure. I then went to MSDN's page and found:

> MsoAutomationSecurityLow turns on all macros and is the default value
>   when you start the program. MsoAutomationSecurityForceDisable disables
>   all macros in all files that are opened programmatically, without
>   showing any security warnings.

As I understand, it has to be `MsoAutomationSecurityLow`. This one works again here.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but any kind of translation is listed in question and all failed.

Comment: @shA.t I understood that, but wanted to share that it worked smoothly for me. And since C# and VB are equivalent, this is an indication that you'll have to check environment issues (security, office version, project references, etc) rather than in the programming part.

Comment: In my c# code simple code of `wordApp.Run("Test");` will raise same error ;).

Comment: please look at my Edit. I think that `msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable` disables VBA in the word app. It might not solve the pb completely, but for sure it does not permit macros to run. @shA.t

Comment: `msoAutomationSecurityLow` is the default value of `AutomationSecurity` and also the error raises again with or without that setting.